# What exactly is meant by "Ladles and Jellyspoons"

Tags: word-meaning

I see this salutation, "Ladles and Jellyspoons", in many places, including [here](http://bussongs.com/songs/ladles-and-jellyspoons.php).

What exactly is meant by this phrase? How did it start to be used?

Comment: It's just nonsense verse (and a play on "ladies and gentlemen". Quite funny, though.

Comment: Oh, dear! Never thought that it would be such. Any historical anecdote behind this?

Comment: None that I know of. Maybe others can enlighten us. Thanks for the link, though. I'm going to print it out.

Comment: How does even one get the inspiration to write such a masterpiece? Did you see the alternative? It is equally funny or even funnier.

Comment: It's a long-standing tradition to make bad puns on Ladies and Gentlemen - comedians from 100 years ago did "Ladies and Germs".